# List<T>.Add of an object gives unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in UgenityAdministrationConsole.exe

Tags: c#, exception, object, initialization, nullreferenceexception

I am getting an unhandled exception of type

> 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   UgenityAdministrationConsole.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

This is happening in my class constructor.

Here is my code:

```
    public static object dummyObject = new object(); // create a dummy object to use for initializing various things

    public class EntityValuesClass
    {
        public List<EntityValue> EntityValues { get; set; }

        public EntityValuesClass(EntityType _entType)
        {
            Type t;
            PropertyInfo[] propInfoArray;
            EntityValue entValue = new EntityValue();

            t = entityTypeToType[_entType];
            propInfoArray = t.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo propItem in propInfoArray)
            {
                entValue.FieldName = propItem.Name;
                entValue.FieldValue = dummyObject;
                EntityValues.Add(entValue);  <------ this is where the error is happening
            }
        }
    }


    public class EntityValue
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public object FieldValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You have an object reference (EntityValues) not set to an instance (new List<EntityValue) of an object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EntityValues` is `null` as you aren't assigning anything to it.

You can add `EntityValues = new List<EntityValue>();` to the start of your constructor to initialise it.

Answer (score 2):

`EntityValues` is null. You never initialized it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize `EntityValue` property first:

```
EntityValues = new List<EntityValue>();
```

On the other hand, according to [CA1002: Do not expose generic lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx) you should consider changing your class to:

```
private List<EntityValue> _entityValues = new List<EntityValue>();
public List<EntityValue> EntityValues
{
    get { return _entityValues; }
}
```